# How can I open a file with extension DAA on Mac?

Tags: file-conversion

How do I open a file with a .daa file extension on my Mac? Is there a Mac program that will convert it to an ISO image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this reference](http://filext.com/file-extension/DAA), .daa is an extension related to the PowerIso application. [This 2008 MacWorld article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080303140509790) suggests an open source application - [DAA Converter for OS X](http://www.twilightedge.com/mac/daaconverter/). The app page states:

> DAA Converter is a free utility for **converting DAA & GBI disk images
>   to ISO format** so they can be accessed on your Mac.
>
> DAA Converter is a native GUI application which wraps the command-line
>   tool, DAA2ISO/GBI2ISO, by Luigi Auriemma.  **It runs on Mac OS X 10.3
>   Panther or later.**

I don't have any .daa files to test with, so I can't verify that this utility works. However, it's a GPL freeware app, so it wouldn't hurt to give it a shot.